# Using <script> in CSS

Tags: html, css, blogger, blogspot

Is there any way to write script in css and call or execute it whenever required ?

I need a `<script>` tag to be executed .

i need something like this..

css code

```
#execute{

<script> ..some script.. </script>

}
```

so whenever i use

```
<html>

.
.
.
.<div id="execute" />
.
.
.
.
</html>
```

so if i change the script changes will be reflected everywhere.

Is it possible?

**EDIT:**

Is it possible to keep my  `<script></script>` tags inside some js file and i will host it. and then i will call some function() from my HTML so that the script will be executed everywhere i need it.

Can someone show me any example, tutorial how i can do it.
I don't have much information about the Js file and how the function should be called.

Thank you all

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: i have got an advertisement script<script></script> and i want to use the ads between post of blogspot, whenever i need it...is it possible ?

Comment: Do you happen to be confusing CSS and Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it *have* to be in CSS? jQuery is a great, simple way to do what you're asking. You put all your style information in the CSS (what it's intended for) and keep your javascript in the html or a .js file. Take a look at http://jquery.com. The code would look something like this

```
$(function() {
    $('#execute')
        .someCoolFunction()
        .anotherCoolFunction();
});
```

You use `$(function() { /* code */ });` to run the code when your document is ready, and you use `$('#execute')` to grab the element with the `execute` tag. You can then do a lot of cool javascript really easily with that jQuery element.

Comment: Have you tried this? `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`
`<script></script>`

Comment: That's awesome ..so i can use jQuery .but where i need to put my <script> ?

Comment: Anywhere on the page. Just make sure your code is wrapped in `$(function() { /* code */ });` so that it will run when the document is ready.

Comment: There are tons of demos, examples, and really good documentation on jQuery's website.

Comment: just reply me back  if i m doing anything wrong ..i will add <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js" t    in the <head> </head> of my site then i will use

Comment: @redEvo let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1088/discussion-between-sangram-and-redevo)

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot mix CSS and Javascript this way.  Why would you want to?

If you simply want a common JavaScript include, do it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourscript.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe a Javascript library like [JQuery](http://www.jquery.org) or [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/) is what you are looking for. It will allow you to add event handlers on tags with certain CSS attributes, which will behave exactly like what you are trying to do right now.

**EDIT**

Here is an example with Dojo pulled from the Google CDN that will popup an alert window when you click on any `<div class="execute"></div>` block:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    <!--
      .execute { background-color: red; height: 25px; }
    -->
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js" ></script> <!-- load Dojo from Google CDN

    <!-- Let's register a onClick handle for any .execute div. -->
    <script>
      dojo.ready(function()  // Dojo will run this after being initialized
      {
          // Get A list of all tags with id execute and add a event onClick
          dojo.query(".execute").connect("onclick", function(evt)
          {
              alert("Event triggered!");
              // ...
          });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="execute">Click me 1</div>
    <br /><br />
    <div class="execute">Click me 2</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Edit 2**

This example uses an onClick event but Dojo (JQuery) allows you to do much more things. For instance if you wanted to dynamically add an image or something onLoad inside .execute divs, you could do it with Dojo (JQuery) in a similar way to this.

Doing it with a library saves you a lot of effort, but if you still want to write and call your own functions from javascript files, this is a rough idea of how you would do it:

```
// myScript.js
function foo()
{
    // ...
}


// page.htm
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="path/to/myScript.js"></script>
  </head>
<!-- ... -->
<div class="execute">
  <script>
  <!--
    // Call foo()
    foo();
  -->
  </script>
</div>
<!-- ... -->
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in standard CSS.

There is a way in which you *can* run code from within the CSS context, using a technology called 'Behaviours', referencing an HTC file (which is basically Javascript) in the stylesheet.

However, this technology is non-standard, and only exists in IE. It is therefore only really used to write hacks to make IE support features that it doesn't have which are in other browsers. An example of this in use is [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/).

If you're working on a site which will never be used in any browser other than IE, and you're happy to use a non-standard technology, then you may consider this to be the exact answer to your question. However I would strongly recommend you don't do this.

More realistically, you should be using a Javascript library such as JQuery, as the functionality you describe is pretty much standard fare for JQuery.

With JQuery, you would write code like this (in a normal script block, not in the CSS!):

```
$('.execute').each(function() {
    /* your code here; it would be run for each element on the page with the class of 'execute' */
}
```

As you can see, it uses a CSS-style selector syntax to select the elements to work with.

(also NB: I've used `execute` as a classname here, not as an ID, because you imply that you want more than one of them -- note that you should never use the same ID more than once in any HTML page; it is invalid. If you need the same thing several times, use a class.

JQuery has functionality to watch for changes to elements, respond to events such as clicks or mouse over, and much more. Other similar libraries such as Prototype, MooTools and Dojo would also be able to do a similar job.

Hope that helps.

[EDIT]
Given the edit to your question, can you not just place the advertisment `<script>` tag inside the `<div>` on the page where you want it?

So with JQuery, you could write something like this to run your ad in each place you want it:

HTML:

```
 ....
 <div class='execute'></div>
 ....
 <div class='execute'></div>
 ....
```

Javascript code (remember to also include the JQuery library, or this won't work):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.execute').each(function() {
        advertisement(this);   //change to whatever the advertisement script function is called.
    });
});
```

Hopefully that will get you started. I can't really help you much more without knowing more about the advertisement script, though.

Also, the people who supplied the advert script should be able to tell you how to use it.

Comment: +1 for good information.learned something new..but i guess it wont solve problem..i have edited the question ..can u take a look ?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really make sense to abstract a script into CSS like that, and even if it was a good idea, it can't be done.

Why do you need to run the same script over and over in different places? Consider whether or not there might be a better or simpler way to do whatever it is you're doing.

Plus, when you include a script with the `src` attribute in the script tag, if you modify the script's source file, the changes persist everywhere.

Comment: agreed ...i have edited the question..suppose in  future, i need to change the script code then i can not go to every post and change it again..so what u suggest ?

Comment: If you have the src tag pointing to the same location in all the references to the script, all you need to do is modify the external script, wherever you prefer to keep it. It will affect everywhere the script is referenced.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can use script to alter the CSS properties of any element in the DOM.